# Extracting specific string between < and >

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to use library `re` to get some data from a file. The data that I need looks like this:

```
g:=Graph<5|{ {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 4} }>
```

So it should be something between `g:=Graph<` and `>`.

I tried

```
with open('Graphs.txt') as f:
    print(re.findall("g:=.*;;",f.read()))
```

but it is not working(it was returning an empty list). Anyone can help me? I am sorry if this is very trivial but I am not experienced.

The text file has a lot of text explaining different types of graphs that is why it has a lot of graphs of the same type in it.

Comment: Do you mean use a capturing group? `g:=Graph<([^<>]+)>` https://regex101.com/r/zny6SJ/1

Comment: You're using `re.findall` which suggests there's more than one occurrance in the input file, Graphs.txt. Please provide a [mre]. It might turn out you need to put in line delimiters and/or enable `re.MULTILINE`. **edit**: Also I just noticed your regex has `;;` but the example data doesn't. What's that about?

Comment: Please elaborate on `not working`. What *exactly* do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: @Thefourthbird your solution worked, if you want to post it as an answer so I can choose it.

Comment: @wjandrea I already got the solution but I will update my question so you can see what was wrong. Thank you for the remarks.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel it returned an empty list, instead of a list with the strings that had a similar pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a repeating pattern for the { digit , digit } part and capture the value in a group.

```
g:=Graph<(\d+\|{ {\d+, \d+}(?:, {\d+, \d+})* })>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VuSMl0/1/)

A less stricter pattern could be using a negated character class matching any char except `<` or `>`

```
g:=Graph<([^<>]+)>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zny6SJ/1)

Answer (score 2):

You might use this regex :

```
g:=Graph<([^>]+)>
```

Otherwise your syntax is correct.